# Search for most recent file under a directory and copy the folder containing it to another directory

Tags: script, batch-file

In my directory I have many files with the same name also in many other subdirectories

example file structure:

> C:\a\first\hello.txt
>   C:\a\second\hello.txt
>   C:\a\third\hello.txt

I need to specifically search for the most recently modified 'hello.txt' (as there are also other files in the directory) and copy its containing folder to C:\b

Am very new to batch so explanations would be fantastic :)

Comment: This is actually surprisingly difficult in plain batch. PowerShell could handle this easily. Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 2):

This is a clumsy collection of commands, and no doubt someone smarter than I ([exempli gratia](https://www.lyndseyscott.com/)) will turn this into something much smaller and more terse, but sometimes it's better while learning to see all the gears spinning.

This batch file, or 'script', relies on **cut**, **head**, and **sed** from Core Utilities for Windows (Open Source) http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm which, if you want to do any kind of batch file writing, makes your life sooooo much easier.

```
C:      
cd \a  
del temp.tmp  
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir hello.txt /b /s') do @echo %%~tF %%F >> temp.tmp  
sort /r temp.tmp > result.tmp   
head -1 result.tmp > temp.tmp  
cut -d: -f 3 temp.tmp | sed s/hello.txt// > temp.tmp  
set /p SOU=<temp.tmp  
CD %SOU%  
copy *.* C:\b\ 
dir c:\b
```

Say WHAT? Here's a little commentary, starting from the fourth line, which I adapted (programmers rarely say *stole*) from the work of a [genius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) over on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874940/display-file-name-and-creation-time-only-of-all-files-in-a-directory-tree):

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir hello.txt /b /s') do @echo %%~tF %%F >> temp.tmp
```

which creates a working file, named **temp.tmp**, built line-by-line, listing every **hello.txt** file under the current directory; each line starts with the date and time of **hello.txt** followed by an [absolute path](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Paths) to **hello.txt**  which looks like

> 10/05/2018 09:27 C:\a\1\hello.txt
>   10/05/2018 09:29 C:\a\2\hello.txt
>   10/05/2018 09:32 C:\a\3\hello.txt

```
sort /r temp.tmp > result.tmp
```

takes the contents of **temp.tmp** and sorts them in reverse order, writing them into **result.tmp**, overwriting whatever was there before (if there was anything), or creating the file if there was no **result.tmp**,  yielding:

> 10/05/2018 09:32 C:\a\3\hello.txt
>   10/05/2018 09:29 C:\a\2\hello.txt
>   10/05/2018 09:27 C:\a\1\hello.txt

```
head -1 result.tmp > temp.tmp
```

does something Windows does not know how to do, so we had to get the [free-as-in-beer](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31717/what-do-the-phrases-free-speech-vs.-free-beer-really-mean/) [Open Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/home.en.html) [Core Utilities package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) to get the **[head](https://interworks.com/blog/dholm/2011/04/19/text-file-manipulation-windows-using-gnu-utilities-head-tail-split/)** command, which here just takes the first line of **result.tmp** and writes it into **temp.tmp**, overwriting whatever was in **temp.tmp** before (the single > ['redirection' operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_files_pipes.htm) overwrites; the >> operator concatenates, adding to what was already in the file) which gives us:

> 10/05/2018 09:32 C:\a\3\hello.txt

```
cut -d: -f 3 temp.tmp | sed s/hello.txt// > temp.tmp
```

This line uses [cut](https://ss64.com/bash/cut.html) to echo only the third field (omitting date and time) of **temp.tmp** and ['pipes'](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_files_pipes.htm) it to another small program, [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), which is so [incredibly awesome](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) that mere words can't explain all it can do. Here we use it to find **hello.txt** and remove it from what we found in **temp.tmp**, and send it on to overwrite **temp.tmp**; now it just contains the path to where the newest instance of **hello.txt** was, to wit:

> \a\3\

(Should you wish, you could consolidate lines 5, 6, and 7 into one with

```
sort /r temp.tmp | head -1 | cut -d: -f 3 | sed s/hello.txt// > temp.tmp
```

but I kept them separate here for teaching purposes.)

OK, now we have the absolute path to the directory of the files we want to copy from, sitting in **temp.tmp** but we need to use that in the batch file so with the command

```
set /p SOU=<temp.tmp
```

we [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) a variable, *SOU*, to what's in **temp.tmp**.

```
CD %SOU%
```

changes the working directory to where the newest instance of **hello.txt** was, and

```
copy *.* C:\b\
```

copies its files to \b on drive C:

How did I do this? Standing on the shoulders of giants, mostly: I started knowing what I needed to begin with was a directory listing of all the **hello.txt** files, a listing which showed the date and time of creation for each file followed by the absolute path.  Once I had that, I just started chopping it up until I got down to just the newest **hello.txt**, and threw away everything which wasn't the path to copy files from.  Kinda like the Esquimeaux sculptor who cut away everything which didn't look like a walrus.

Note: When you are testing, line by line, you use a single % for variables; once it works and you put it into a batch file, you use a double %%, which confused me greatly until I read [an explanation mentioning it](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Quoting_and_escaping).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to bash (possibly through cygwin, WSL, min-gw etc), here is a one liner (assuming you're already inside your desired parent directory:

```
cp $(dirname `find . -type f -exec ls -l {} --time-style=+%s \; | sort -nrk 7 | awk '{print $8}' | head -1`)/* "c:\b"
```

this assume cygwin. For other you may need to modify the target path slightly. You may need to make sure first that `dirname`, `find`, `sort`, `awk`, `head` are available